# Python: daily average function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, function, average

I am trying to make a function that returns a list/array with the daily averages for a variable from either one of 3 csv files

Each csv file is similar to this:

```
date, time, variable1, variable2, variable3
2021-01-01,01:00:00,1.43738,25.838,22.453
2021-01-01,02:00:00,2.08652,21.028,19.099
2021-01-01,03:00:00,1.39101,23.18,20.925
2021-01-01,04:00:00,0.76506,22.053,19.974
```

The date contains the entire year of 2021 with increments of 1 hour

```
def daily_average(data, station, variable):
```

The function has 3 parameters:
data
station: One of the 3 csv files
variable: Either variable 1 or 2 or 3

Libraries such as datetime, calendar and numpy can be used
Pandas can also be used

Answer (score 0):

Well.
First of all - try to do it yourself before asking a question.
It will help you to learn things.

But now to your question.

```
csv_lines_test = [
"date, time, variable1, variable2, variable3\n",
"2021-01-01,01:00:00,1.43738,25.838,22.453\n",
"2021-01-01,02:00:00,2.08652,21.028,19.099\n",
"2021-01-01,03:00:00,1.39101,23.18,20.925\n",
"2021-01-01,04:00:00,0.76506,22.053,19.974\n",
]

import datetime as dt

def daily_average(csv_lines, date, variable_num):
    # variable_num should be 1-3
    avg_arr = []
    # Read csv file line by line.
    for i, line in enumerate(csv_lines):
        if i == 0:
            # Skip headers
            continue
        line = line.rstrip()
        values = line.split(',')
        date_csv = dt.datetime.strptime(values[0], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        val_arr = [float(val) for val in values[2:]]
        if date == date_csv:
            avg_arr.append(val_arr[variable_num-1])
    return sum(avg_arr) / len(avg_arr)


avg = daily_average(csv_lines_test, dt.date(2021, 1, 1), 1)
print(avg)
```

If you want to read data directly from csv file:

```
with open("csv_file_path.csv", 'r') as f:
    data = [line for line in f]
    avg = daily_average(data, dt.date(2021, 1, 1), 1)
    print(avg)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the code. However, I am unable to read the data directly from the csv file. I have used this: with open("./data/filename.csv", 'r') as f:
    data = [line for line in f]
    avg = daily_average(data, dt.date(2021, 1, 1), 1)
    print(avg)