# Python : function for daily average using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, function, average

Python beginner needing help in an assignment here. I need to make a function that returns a list/array with the daily averages (i.e., 365 values) for a particular variable and csv file name

The function signature:

```
def daily_average(data, csv_file_name1:str, variable:str):
```

There are 3 csv files containing data like this (Example listed below is only a part of the file):

```
date time variable1 variable2 variable3
2021-01-01 01:00:00 6.08624 21.3 18.6
2021-01-01 02:00:00 7.40564 45.1 40.3
2021-01-01 03:00:00 5.01157 25.6 23.9
2021-01-01 04:00:00 12.76834 20.8 18.1
2021-01-01 05:00:00 9.09745 20.9 21.7
```

NumPy can be used. Pandas can also be used but I'm not proficient in it, so I'd prefer to not use it.

Comment: That function has no name, and what is 'data' supposed to be?

Comment: you should probably read in the file with pandas https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-read-csv-using-pandas-read_csv/ and then select the variable column https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html to get towards the result that you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: daily average function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74632400/python-daily-average-function)

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where pandas is a good approach. Finding the daily averages can be written as a `groupby` operation, which turns the problem into a one-liner where you (1) group according the date in the `date_time` column, then (2) compute the mean over the numeric entries.

I've duplicated some lines from the input to demonstrate this:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data_file = StringIO("""date_time,variable1,variable2,variable3
2021-01-01 01:00:00,6.08624,21.3,18.6
2021-01-01 02:00:00,7.40564,45.1,40.3
2021-01-01 03:00:00,5.01157,25.6,23.9
2021-01-01 04:00:00,12.76834,20.8,18.1
2021-01-01 05:00:00,9.09745,20.9,21.7
2021-01-02 01:00:00,6.08624,21.3,18.6
2021-01-02 02:00:00,7.40564,45.1,40.3
2021-01-03 03:00:00,5.01157,25.6,23.9
2021-01-04 04:00:00,12.76834,20.8,18.1
2021-01-05 05:00:00,9.09745,20.9,21.7""")

df = pd.read_csv(data_file, parse_dates=[0])

print(df.groupby(by=df['date_time'].dt.date).mean(numeric_only=True))
```

Output:

```
date_time                                  
2021-01-01   8.073848      26.74      24.52
2021-01-02   6.745940      33.20      29.45
2021-01-03   5.011570      25.60      23.90
2021-01-04  12.768340      20.80      18.10
2021-01-05   9.097450      20.90      21.70
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I just return one of the 3 variables?

Comment: If you bind the result of `df.groupby` to a variable (e.g. `out = df.groupby(...)`), you should be able to return `out.variable1`, `out.variable2`, or any similar column indexing operations.

Comment: Also, how do I implement it as a function?

Comment: That depends on what you want the function to do, or how you intend to use the function. As general code refactoring advice in Python: (1) add a function signature, (2) indent code below the function signature, (3) adjust variables, (4) add a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I echo the use of pandas in this instance. Another alternative is to resample the data on the daily time frame. Can specify the aggregation method in the `resample_dict` on a column basis as well.

```
resample_dict = {                                                                                                             
    'variable1': 'mean',
    'variable2': 'mean',
    'variable3': 'mean'
}

daily_average = daily_average.resample('D', closed='left', label='left').apply(ohlc_dict)
```